# MVC .NET - Passing a user model to a razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, razor

I am trying to unit test razor views. In particular, I am trying to write for an Admin button - that appears on the main toolbar iff the user logged in is an Admin.

Currently we do not have any tests, and the way it works is by setting up a static object called CurrentUser.

Razor:

```
@if CurrentUser.IsAdmin()
{
     <button>admin</button>
}
```

However, since we are invoking CurrentUser - a static object set elsewhere in the project, I am not sure if we can not unit test this razor view independently. I would think we have to make a User object, have an instance of the user logged in, and inject it into the razor view.

eg.

```
Controller
{ 
    ActionResult Index(){
        var currentUser = //somehow get current user
        return View(currentUser);
}
```

But what if the razor view I am test is a _Layout page? Would I have to inject the current user whenever I am rendering a page?

Is there a way I can inject current user to the parent of View? Maybe I have to override the View method? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have authentication, you can use in your view:

    @if User.IsInRole("Admin")

instead of the static class CurrentUser.

Comment: true, but User is still a static object. For setting up my tests - how can I set a fake user that is logged in and happens to be an admin - that way I can test whether my button appears (test passes) or does not appear (test fails). Do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the LogOn Action on the Account Controller first to be logged in:

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void Index()
        {
            // Arrange
            AccountController account = new AccountController();
            HomeController controller = new HomeController();

            var accRes = account.LogOn(new Models.LogOnModel() { UserName = "mylogin", Password = "abc123" }, string.Empty);

            // Act
            ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; it would work, but ideally, I would like to test the view by itself without the involvement of controllers. For example, the _layout is not linked to a particular controller.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using an DI (dependency injection) container (like ninject)?
Then you could add the CurrentUser to the Controllers constructor like this:

```
class Controller 
{  
    private _currentUser;
    public Controller(IUser currentUser) {
        _currentUser = currentUser
    }

    ActionResult Index(){ 
        return View(_currentUser); 
    }
}
```

And assign the static class to the DI (in case of ninject):

```
ninjectKernel.Bind<IUser>().To<CurrentUser>();
```

In the Unit Test you can simply instantiate the controller with your test user:

```
[TestMethod]         
public void Index()         
{         
    // Arrange         
    CurrentUser currentUser = new CurrentUser() { Role = "Admin" };        
    HomeController controller = new HomeController(currentUser);                 

    // Act         
    ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;
    Assert.IsTrue(((CurrentUser)result.ViewData.Model).IsAdmin());
}
```

But you cannot directly test the HTML output by that. You can only check if your model is set/behaving correctly.